# Writing a dictionary to a csv file, one line for each key, value pair, one cell for each element in value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key-value pairs {company name1: [url1,url2,url3],company name2:[url1,url2,url3]}. I want to write it so that for each row in my CSV file, one cell will be for the company name and each cell on the same row will contain a single URL. So far, I am only able to get all the URLs into one cell.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in contact.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

It gives me the output of company name in 1 cell and ['url1','url2','url3'] in the adjacent cell. Is there any way to remove the [] and '' as well?

my expected output would be:

company1 url1 url2 url3

company2 url1 url2 url3

and so on

Comment: Please share one example input and example expected and current output to clear what is your expectation and what is the current data you are getting.
From your question, I could understand current output you are getting. 
Are you expecting output as follows:

some_company_name,url1,url2,url3

or 

same_company_name,url1

same_company_name,url2
same_company_name,url3

Comment: @VivekAgrawal hello ive reedited my question to show my expected output I would want my output to be like the first one you've mentioned if its possible

Comment: Please, also share the input

Comment: @pandasandnumpy: Your "value" object is most likely a list as well. Just use a nested loop to create seperate values for those as well.

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski hello my input is a dictionary consisting of company name as key and a list containing 3 URLs related to the company as value

Comment: @pandasandnumpy that's not a CSV file. That's just a text file with your own custom format. A CSV is a text file with Comma Separated Values. It has no cells. There's a fixed number of columns and each record is stored in a separate line. Each Value is Separated by others by a Comma - that's what the acronyms mean.

Comment: @pandasandnumpy you haven't selected any of the answer. Please let contributors know if you got the answer or you are expecting something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, as long as you are sure that there will be always exactly 3 urls:

```
import csv
contact = {"Company": ["test.com", "example.com", "stackoverflow.com"], "Company2": ["test.com", "example.com", "stackoverflow.com"]}
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in contact.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value[0], value[1], value[2]])
```

Comment: Could replace the last line with ```writer.writerow([key] + contact[key])``` in case there are ever more/less URLs

Answer (score 0):

If the number of urls are variable for a company, then you can do following:

```
import csv
data = { "company1": ["url1","url2","url3"], "company2": ["url1","url2","url3"]}

with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for key, values in data.items():
       row = []
       row.append(key)
       row.extend(values)
       writer.writerow(row)
```